# MonoTouch error MT2002: Can not resolve reference

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a iOS/MonoTouch project which is using a lot of reflection. Everything works great, but when I compile the **Debug|iPhone** version I get the error:

> **error MT2002: Can not resolve reference: System.Boolean System.Reflection.PropertyInfo::op_Equality(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)**

Funny thing is that the Release|iPhone build works fine.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `==` operator overload for `PropertyInfo`, which is internally named `op_Equality`, is available on .NET 4.0 and later. IOW it's not available in the version of `mscorlib.dll` that ships with MonoTouch (which is a superset of the Silverlight, 2.1, profile).

What's happening is likely a different version of a pre-compiled assembly that is used when building **Debug** (versus **Release**). This version uses methods that are not available in MonoTouch and this will results in errors while either linking or AOT-ing your application.

**Solution:** re-compile this assembly with the version of mscorlib.dll that ships with MonoTouch. This will avoid the reference to `op_Equality` (and uses `Equals`) and the build should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! What actually happened: I use Visual Studio on my PC for editing and I can even build. Of course I have to rebuild on the Mac to be able to run. I guess the build on the PC pulled in the wrong mscorlib. After deleting the obj and bin folders in all projects, recompiling on the Mac worked fine.

Comment: I come back to this answer every time I have this problem. I just keep forgetting about the solution. :-)

Comment: @DanAbramov that should become an historical fact/FAQ soon ;-)